# Changing the state of an anchor to active via javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Im having an issue getting the state of an anchor tag to be active. Say I am on the home page, I want the home navigation link to have an active state so it has a different color. Here is what im doing at the moment.  I am referencing jquery.  I have stubbed in alerts to make sure my script is getting hit. Here is what I last tried.

```
<div class="grid__unit one-whole">
<nav role="navigation">
    <ul id="nav--primary" class="navbar navbar--menu">
        <li><a class="navitem" href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a class="navitem" href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
        <li><a class="navitem" id="myNavButton" href="myLink">myTitle</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

with  css

```
a:hover, a:active {
color: #b74800;
}
```

and script

```
<script>    
$(document).ready(function () {        
    $("#myNavButton").addClass("active");
});
</script>
```

EDIT 1:

I have tried adding an a.active tag to the css and script as follows, with no success.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var path = location.pathname.length ? location.pathname : window.location.href;
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $("#nav--primary").find('a[href*="' + path + '"]').addClass("active");
});
</script>
```

with css

```
a:hover, a:active, a.active {
color: #b74800;
}
```

EDIT 2 --SOLVED

Comment: [pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) != class

Comment: Oops. I do have the # in there in my code. edited.

Comment: What do you get in the console if you add `console.log($("#nav--primary").find('a[href*="' + path + '"]'));`

Comment: I found a solution to the functionality that i wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the desired functionality, I ended up adding an ID to the parent list item and on document ready, I added a class to that list item.  In css i added another class for this.

```
#nav--primary .is--selected .navitem,
#nav--primary .is--selected .navitem:hover,
#nav--primary .is--selected .navitem:focus {
  background: #colorhere; /* primary nav current page background color */
  color: #colorhere /* primary nav current page text color */
}
```

with script

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myLiID").addClass("is--selected");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS you have missed `a.active` declaration. Try with:

```
a:hover, a:active, a.active {
  color: #b74800;
}
```

In jQuery to get element by ID, you have to use `#myNavButton`, so:

```
$("#myNavButton").addClass("active");
```

Answer (score 0):

So you need to do two things:

#### 1. make a css class of `a.active`

```
a:hover, a:active, a.active {
  color: #b74800;
}
```

#### 2. do this in jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    var path = location.pathname.lenght ? location.pathname : window.location.href;   
    $('.active').removeClass('active');    
    $("#nav--primary").find('a[href*="'+path+'"]').addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: This would be the most flexible approach.

Comment: @NickR yeah seems to be but there is a catch if OP has his homepage with an absoute path like `http://www.abc.net` then `location.path` will be failed.

Comment: `var path = location.pathname.lenght ? location.pathname : window.location.href; ` i think this would be better.

Comment: i tried both the original and the other way to get the path.  neither seem to have done anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
#nav--primary a.active {
   color: #b74800;
}
```

Add this style.